# Is there a way to add users automatically into gitlab?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, bash, shell, gitlab

I've got a gitlab running on server. For now, I've also got just a list of users and emails needed to be add into gitlab. Is there a way to do this automatically? (i.e. by script/service)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [GitLab API to create users](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/6-2-stable/doc/api/users.md#user-creation) in a script.  [Recent versions of curl can url-encode](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html) POST data for you.  Otherwise spaces will have to be `%20` and `--data` instead of `--data-urlencode`.

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: QVy1PB7sTxfy4pqfZM1U" --data-urlencode "email=jon@doe.com&password=defaultpassword&username=jdoe&name=Jon Doe" "http://example.com/api/v3/users"
```

Curl is the path of least resistance with your preferred shell language (in my case Bash).  If you don't want to use curl to script creating your users there are numerous libraries for different languages to interact with the GitLab API.  Take your pick.  Popular libraries include:

- Java - [java-gitlab-api](https://github.com/timols/java-gitlab-api)
- PHP - [php-gitlab-api](https://github.com/m4tthumphrey/php-gitlab-api)
- Python - [pyapi-gitlab](https://github.com/Itxaka/pyapi-gitlab), [python-gitlab](https://github.com/gpocentek/python-gitlab), or [python-gitlab3](https://github.com/alexvh/python-gitlab3)
- Ruby - [Gitlab wrapper](https://github.com/NARKOZ/gitlab)

I'm sure there are many more API libs for other languages just google for your preferred language and include *GitLab API* as part of the query.

Comment: You can also skip the url-encode and post json data.
curl -X POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: QVy1PB7sTxfy4pqfZM1U" -d '{"name":"John Doe","username":"john.doe" 
 http://example.com/api/v4/users
1. make sure you have all the required fills
2. you can work with a nice editor and then kill all the whitespaces http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: Forgot to mention, [since 9.0 it's better to use v4](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/v3_to_v4.html#v3-to-v4-version)

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible (not tested yet), it could have been done through the **[gitlab-shell](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell)** library, which exposes the API of [gitlab](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq).
But adding a user isn't part of its API yet (it only add ssh keys).

[Issue 1942](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/1942) does mention there is an API in gitlab itself.
You can take example on tester like [`spec/features/gitlab_flavored_markdown_spec.rb`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/spec/features/gitlab_flavored_markdown_spec.rb):

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "GitLab Flavored Markdown" do
  let(:project) { create(:project_with_code) }
  let(:issue) { create(:issue, project: project) }
  let(:merge_request) { create(:merge_request, source_project: project, target_project: project) }
  let(:fred) do
    u = create(:user, name: "fred")
    project.team << [u, :master]
    u
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

[cli-gitlab](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cli-gitlab) installed through npm is working pretty well for me for both LDAP (AD) and local users. It saves the token of the 'admin' user which makes it a lot easier to script/automate things.