# How do I import members of one GitLab group into another

Tags: gitlab

Does somebody know how I can import all members of one group into another in GitLab, rather than doing it manually one by one?

Comment: Hi @momme - welcome to the site. Hope you get the answers you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The only native feature which comes close is in [`lib/tasks/gitlab/bulk_add_permission.rake`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/8cd882355edf7b88011ad7fca13ccba5f948001b/lib/tasks/gitlab/bulk_add_permission.rake), which is mentioned in "[User management](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/56a456b43dba7d772db45e2b73aa18b5eab53d37/doc/raketasks/user_management.md#add-user-as-a-developer-to-all-groups)"

```
# omnibus-gitlab
sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:import:all_users_to_all_groups

# installation from source
bundle exec rake gitlab:import:all_users_to_all_groups RAILS_ENV=production
```

You could take that as a model to develop our own task.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of such a feature. But you can script it with the API.  We use it here to add all users to one single group (all users to all groups is not feasible for our case).

Helpful documentation: http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/README.html,   http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/users.html and http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/groups.html

There is also a respond to another question that might be helpful and lists also various modules for various programming languages: [Is there a way to add users automatically into gitlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19863786/is-there-a-way-to-add-users-automatically-into-gitlab)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution to Assign all Gitlab users to one particular group.

Here's the solution:

Create this file:

> /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/finder_import.rake

With this content:

> ```
> namespace :gitlab do   namespace :finder do
>
> desc "GitLab | Add all users to group Colaboradores (admin users are added as owners)"
> task importall: :environment  do |t, args|
>   user_ids = User.where(admin: false).pluck(:id)
>   admin_ids = User.where(admin: true).pluck(:id)
>   groups = Group.where(name: "Colaboradores")
>
>   puts "Importing #{user_ids.size} users into #{groups.size} groups"
>   puts "Importing #{admin_ids.size} admins into #{groups.size} groups"
>   groups.each do |group|
>     puts "Importing into #{group.name}"
>     group.add_users(user_ids, GroupMember::DEVELOPER)
>     group.add_users(admin_ids, GroupMember::OWNER)
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> end end

Run this command:

> gitlab-rake gitlab:finder:importall